# How do I download and combine multiple files in r?

Tags: r, download

I am endeavoring to combine files but find myself writing very redundant code, which is cumbersome. I have looked at the documentation but for some reason cannot find anything about how to do this.

Basically, I download the code from my native machine, and then want to combine the exact same columns for each file (the only difference is year).

Can you help?

- I download the code from my machine (`"C:/SAM/CODE1_2005.csv"` then `"C:/SAM/CODE1_2006.csv"` then `"C:/SAM/CODE1_2007.csv"`, until 2016.
- I then define the columns, all the same for each year I have downloaded, such as `COLLEGESCORECARD05_A<-subset(COLLEGESCORECARD05, select=c(ï..UNITID,OPEID,OPEID6,INSTNM))` and so forth...
- and then combine the files into one database.

The issue is that this seems inefficient. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Can you post the script itself? I'm not sure what you mean by point 2. Do all the files have different columns headers initially and then you change them?

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Thanks for replying. All the files have the same pattern: First, I used downloadfile to download the url for IPEDS data over ten years; each file has the exact same columns. I then reduce is to C:/SAM/Code1_2005 through Code1_2014. I would like to know if I could use something like C:/SAM?Code1_2005:Code1_2014 to download everything into one megafile so I do not have to write separate code for each of the ten years...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of the `.csv` files in the folder and then read them all together into a single df with `purrr::map_df`. You can add a column to differentiate between files then

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- list.files(path="C://SAM", 
                  pattern="*.csv") %>%
  purrr::map_df(function(x) readr::read_csv(x) %>%
  mutate(filename=gsub(" .csv", "", basename(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks...this looks as though it'll work for me too, but my initial attempts got me an error message because some of the .csv files, despite having the same variable name, seem to register as containing data in two different formats (character and double). Likely, this is a data entry issue, but I'd rather deal with that after I've combined my files. Is there a way to disregard this formatting issue? TIA

Comment: The `read_csv` function has a `col_types` argument, where you could set the variable type to character and decide whether to keep as character or double after reading them in

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of seeming icky for self-promotion, I wrote a function that does exactly this ([`desiderata::apply_to_files()`](https://github.com/DesiQuintans/desiderata)):

```
# Apply a function to every file in a folder that matches a regex pattern

rain <- apply_to_files(path = "Raw data/Rainfall", pattern = "csv", 
                       func = readr::read_csv, col_types = "Tiic", 
                       recursive = FALSE, ignorecase = TRUE, 
                       method = "row_bind")

dplyr::sample_n(rain, 5)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#> 
#>   orig_source_file       Time                 Tips    mV Event 
#>   <chr>                  <dttm>              <int> <int> <chr> 
#> 1 BOW-BM-2016-01-15.csv  2015-12-17 03:58:00     0  4047 Normal
#> 2 BOW-BM-2016-01-15.csv  2016-01-03 00:27:00     2  3962 Normal
#> 3 BOW-BM-2016-01-15.csv  2015-11-27 12:06:00     0  4262 Normal
#> 4 BIL-BPA-2018-01-24.csv 2015-11-15 10:00:00     0  4378 Normal
#> 5 BOW-BM-2016-08-05.csv  2016-04-13 19:00:00     0  4447 Normal
```

In this case, all of the files have identical columns and order (Time, Tips, mV, Event), so I can just `method = "row_bind"` and the function will automatically add the filename as an extra column. There are other methods available:

> "full_join" (the default) returns all columns and rows. "left_join" returns all rows from the first file, and all columns from subsequent files. "inner_join" returns rows from the first file that have matches in subsequent files.

Internally, the function builds a list of files in the path (recursive or not), runs an `lapply()` on the list, and then handles merging the new list of dataframes into a single dataframe:

```
apply_to_files <- function(path, pattern, func, ..., recursive = FALSE, ignorecase = TRUE, 
                          method = "full_join") {
    file_list <- list.files(path = path,
                            pattern = pattern,
                            full.names = TRUE,      # Return full relative path.
                            recursive = recursive,  # Search into subfolders.
                            ignore.case = ignorecase)

    df_list <- lapply(file_list, func, ...)

    # The .id arg of bind_rows() uses the names to create the ID column.
    names(df_list) <- basename(file_list)

    out <- switch(method,
                  "full_join"  = plyr::join_all(df_list, type = "full"),
                  "left_join"  = plyr::join_all(df_list, type = "left"),
                  "inner_join" = plyr::join_all(df_list, type = "inner"),
                  # The fancy joins don't have orig_source_file because the values were
                  # getting all mixed together.
                  "row_bind"   = dplyr::bind_rows(df_list, .id = "orig_source_file"))

    return(invisible(out))
}
```